# Replace number by string in text file

Tags: python

Given a string as input, I want to find and convert the integer elements of the line with the string `num`. Here is an example:

input:

```
"abc 123 def 1 in 1s and 100MB"
```

output:

```
"abc >num< def >num< in 1s and 100MB"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: huh? not sure what is going on here

Comment: It's programming language of the highest level :)

Comment: so you only want to replace numbers that a space on both sides right?

Comment: yes! @Jacobr365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html):

```py
import re

s = "abc 123 def 1 in 1s and 100MB"

print(re.sub(r"\b\d+\b", ">num<", s))
# output: "abc >num< def >num< in 1s and 100MB"
```

The regular expression string `r"\b\d+\b"` matches a character string that consists of at least one numeral character (`\d+`) enclosed by word boundaries (`\b`). The `\b` part also matches the beginning and the end of a string.

The call to `re.sub()` replaces all occurrences of a matching character string in the third argument `s`  by the second argument (`">num<"`).

Answer (score 4):

That is how.

```
text_in = "abc 123 def 1 in 1s and 100MB"
text_out = ' '.join(['>num<' if x.isnumeric() else x for x in text_in.split()])
print(text_out)  # prints: abc >num< def >num< in 1s and 100MB
```

I took the liberty to assume that you can read the text from a file and can also write the new text to a file so I am skipping those parts.

It all boils down to the use of [`isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric).